# how to get contain count based on sharepoint list with linq?

Tags: c#, linq, sharepoint

i have a sharepoint list, lets call it students.

```
name  | surname | username
------|---------|---------- 
test  | test1   | test11
test2 | test2   | test22
test3 | test3   | test33
```

i keep the student names based on manager, adding to sharepoint list with;

```
String.Join(",", ListBox2.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Select(i => i.Text).ToArray());
```

and i have another list lets call it manages

```
manager | students      
--------|---------------
man1    | test11,test22 
man2    | test33,test11
```

so what i need is each student's manager count, in counter table;

```
studentuName     |   count
-----------------|---------
test11           |    2
test22           |    1
test33           |    1
```

i call them as a list (there will be much more better ways for calling them, i'm just giving example)

```
List<string> students (has value "test11", "test22", "test33")
List<string> manages (has value "test11,test22" , "test33,test11")
```

so how can i get that, how many manager each student have , with linq ?

thank you

---

**Edit**
With @Servy 's answer i can get

```
List<string> managers = new List<string> { "a,b", "a,b,c,d", "a,c", "c,d,f", "a,f,c,b" }; 

var query = managers.SelectMany(manager => manager.Select(student => new { manager, student })); 

var finalQuery = query.GroupBy(pair => pair.student).Select(group => new { Student = group.Key, Count = group.Count() });
```

it also retrurns me the count of comma "," is there any way to avoid that?
and also is there any way to do merge them with single query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we'll transform the manager list from a single valued manager with a multi-valued list of students to where each "row" has a single manager and a single student.  We'll do this by creating additional "rows" for each student in that value of the list for managers.

```
var query = managers.SelectMany(manager => 
    manager.students.Select(student => new { manager, student }));
```

Now we can just group these items by `student` and count the size of the group:

```
var finalQuery = query.GroupBy(pair => pair.student)
    .Select(group => new { Student = group.Key, Count = group.Count()});
```

(You can combine those into one query.)

Comment: thank you, that was what i want i can get result with;

`List<string> managers = new List<string> { "a,b", "a,b,c,d", "a,c", "c,d,f", "a,f,c,b" };`
        
`var query = managers.SelectMany(manager => manager.Select(student => new { manager, student }));`

`var finalQuery = query.GroupBy(pair => pair.student).Select(group => new { Student = group.Key, Count = group.Count() });`

but it also returns me the count of ',' (comma) is there any way to avoid from that? and also how can i do that with single query?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I think it is what you are trying to accomplish:

```
  List<string> Students = new List<string>() { "Test1", "Test2" };
  List<string> Manager = new List<string>(){"Test1","Test1","Test3"};

            var counter = Manager.Count(m => m == Students[0]);
            Console.WriteLine(counter);
            Console.ReadLine();
```

This will allow you to create a loop that goes through each student in the list and get the count of associated managers

Comment: This is ungodly inefficient, as you're looping through all of that data for each student.

Comment: Well what he is doing is inefficient to begin with. It would be much better to normalize the data so that there is less duplication of data and easier to manage, but given the question, I don't think this is all that inefficient.

Comment: You're essentially searching through the entire `manager` list *for each student*.  Unless there is a *very* small number of both managers and students, that's going to be a problem.

Comment: @gcoleman0828 you are right what im doing is inefficient. i got a manager like that. i told too many times thats not efficient but he told me to keep data with comma. thats what i have to do like that. thank you so much.